# Scala - How to iterate over a Vector[String] and merge elements missing a newline character?

Tags: string, algorithm, scala, vector

I'm working with data coming over the network which gets truncated/or are not complete messages. A complete message is a string terminated by a newline character. All incoming messages are received as a String and will be stored in a buffer which is of type Vector[String] for performance. Also note that more then one message can be stored in the incoming String, each (should be) delimited by a newline character. I'm looking for an efficient way to split the incoming string on the newline character and append it to the Vector[String] buffer, merging a partial message if any with the next partial message from the next received messages String. All messages are ordered, so partial messages will be next to each other at all times. What would be an efficient way of doing this? I'm essentially looking to create a message framing protocol that is delimited by the newline character.

```
example

received messages : "aaa\nbbb\ncc"
received messages : "c\nddd\neee\n"
received messages : "fff"

so the Vector[String] buffer would contain

("aaa\n", "bbb\n", "ccc\n", "ddd\n", "eee\n")
with "fff" marked as partial to be merged in the future
```

here's what I came up with, but I'm sure there is something better. I would like to remove the "require" also and have it work in all scenarios. Please note that the following code doesn't handle partial messages received in the add method, and that is mainly what I'm looking for in the solution.

Thanking you in advance - Francis

```
class MessageBuffer(delimiter: String = "\n") extends Traversable[String] {
  var buffer = Vector.empty[String]

  def add(messages: String): Unit = {
    val msgs = StringContext.treatEscapes(messages)
    require(msgs.takeRight(1) == this.delimiter, "Each message must end with a newline character")
    this.buffer = this.buffer ++ msgs.split(s"(?<=${this.delimiter})")
  }

  def get: Option[String] = this.buffer.headOption match {
    case Some(s) =>
      this.buffer = this.buffer.drop(1)
      Some(s)
    case None => None
  }

  def foreach[Unit](f: (String) => Unit) = this.buffer.foreach(f)
}
```

here's how I would use it

```
val buffer = new MessageBuffer()


buffer.add("aaa\nbbb\ncc")
buffer.add("c\nddd\neee\n")
buffer.add("fff")

println("r: " + buffer.get.map(_.trim)) // would output Some("aaa\n")
println("r: " + buffer.get.map(_.trim)) // would output Some("bbb\n")
println("r: " + buffer.get.map(_.trim)) // would output Some("ccc\n")
println("r: " + buffer.get.map(_.trim)) // would output Some("ddd\n")
println("r: " + buffer.get.map(_.trim)) // would output Some("eee\n")
println("r: " + buffer.get.map(_.trim)) // would output None, note that "fff" would be in the buffer as a partial message
```

Comment: input.mkString.split("\n")

Comment: "efficient" and "elegant" will pull you in opposite directions here.  Which one is more important?

Comment: efficient is more important